# Help Editing Short Monologue

Tags: learning, topolect, sentence-structure, word, writing

Is anyone willing to help me edit this monologue for grammatical errors? If so, I would really appreciate it. I have also included the pinyin in case it helps to understand what I meant. I have chosen the most simple words I know to make performing it easier. Thank you.

我下课以后常常去我的实习。 我以后我的实习我有课一遍。 我的最后课六时完毕某些天， 八时其他天。 然后我常常开始我的回家作业。 至少有一次每个星期我有Amnesty International会议. 这是一个人权组我跟我的男朋友开始。 如果我有会议，我得回家作业我开始后。 我的奖学金需求五个课，所以我有课每天。 周末，我也很多了学习。 如果我有时间，我星期五试试玩儿跟我的朋友们，和星期日吃饭跟我的妈妈。 有时我恐怕没有时候。 如实, 我很忙和不能等到休息。 但是， 我有这些机会是很祝福。

Wǒ xiàkè yǐhòu chángcháng qù wǒ de shíxí. Wǒ yǐhòu wǒ de shíxí wǒ yǒu kè yībiàn. Wǒ de zuìhòu kè liù shí wánbì mǒu xiē tiān, bā shí qítā tiān. Ránhòu wǒ chángcháng kāishǐ wǒ de huí jiā zuòyè. Zhìshǎo yǒu yīcì měi gè xīngqí wǒ yǒu Amnesty International huìyì. Zhè shì yīgè rénquán zǔ wǒ gēn wǒ de nán péngyǒu kāishǐ. Rúguǒ wǒ yǒu huìyì, wǒ dé huí jiā zuòyè wǒ kāishǐ hòu. Wǒ de jiǎngxuéjīn xūqiú wǔ gè kè, suǒyǐ wǒ yǒu kè měitiān. Zhōumò, wǒ yě hěnduōle xuéxí. Rúguǒ wǒ yǒushíjiān, wǒ xīngqíwǔ shì shì wán er gēn wǒ de péngyǒumen, hé xīngqírì chīfàn gēn wǒ de māmā. Yǒu shí wǒ kǒngpà méiyǒu shíhòu. Rúshí, wǒ hěn máng hé bùnéng děngdào xiūxí. Dànshì, wǒ yǒu zhèxiē jīhuì shì hěn zhùfú.

Comment: If you have questions on specific word usage or grammar structures, it's worth creating a new question to ask about that (as long as it hasn't been asked before). Questions on this site should be generalize enough that the answer will help others who have a similar issue.

Comment: Each one sentence at least have one or several mistake. Look like you just pile word and character together. There is Chinese saying "No learn walk then want run, Jack will stumble and fall". This do you no good. First learn basic grammar and phrase, then do paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

### Correction

我下课以后常常去实习 （ i often go to intern-ship whenever the class is finish ).

实习以后我还有一堂课（After the inter-ship i still have a lesson).

我的最后一堂课有时会在六点钟结束，而其它天都会在八点钟结束。 (My last lesson will ended at 6 o'Clock sometimes,while others day will ended at 8 o'Clock) .

然后我就会开始做作业。（Then i will start to do my homework) .

每周至少有一天我都会有个Amnesty International会议. （At least one day a week i will have a meeting of Amnesty International.

这组/会议是由我和我男朋友举办/开始，它是关于人权。(This group/meeting is organized/started by me and my boyfriend, It's about human rights.

如果我有会议，我得回家作业我开始后。// im not sure what you're trying to express here ,perhaps you can translate it to English first and then i will help you to translate it back to Chinese/

奖学金的条件是必须拥有五个科目，所以我几乎每天都有课。(The requirements of scholarships is must have five subjects, therefore i almost have classes everyday.

周末，我也必须学习。 (Weekend, i have to learn also)

如果我有空闲的时间，我会尝试在星期五和朋友一起出去游玩及在星期日与妈妈一起共餐. (If i have free time, i will try to go out and play with friends on Friday, and having meals with mother on Sunday.

有时我担心我没时间。 (Sometimes I worry that I do not have time).

如实, 我很忙和不能等到休息。 // im not sure what you're trying to express here

但是, 我觉得这些机会是很庆幸的 。 （However, I feel that these opportunities are very fortunate)

Answer (score 1):

I'm Chinese native student, show me the English original text if possible.
我下课以后常常去实习。 我以后我的实习我有课一遍(I can't quite understand this sentience)。 我的最后一节课有时六点结束，其它时间八点结束。（it's suggested to state if the time is pm. or am.） 然后（我常常is unnecessary）开始我的家庭作业。 每个星期我有至少有一次Amnesty International会议. 这是我跟我的男朋友建立(we say 建立 instead of 开始 to express the meaning of establish)的一个人权组。 如果我有会议，我得回家作业我开始后(not clear about your meaning)。 我的奖学金需求五个课，所以我每天有课。 周末，我也有很多学习。 如果我有时间，我星期五跟我的朋友们玩，星期日跟我的妈妈吃饭，但是经常没有时间。 确实, 我很忙，几乎没有休息（not quite clear, too）。不管怎么说，我有这个（what机会）机会还是很开心的。